# Show one image depending of data on more than one column

Tags: php, image

Having a db with 4 columns (am_in, am_out, pm_in and pm_out) that holds the time recorded by the users I like to show if the user is in the office (user has recorded am_in and pm_in).
I like to show an image in green when they are in and another image in red if they are out.
The code below shows the images but show as many images as the columns are not empty.
All I want is to show just one image at the time either the green image if user is in or red image if user is out.

PHP knowledge = Basic

```
    <?php
    if ($row_io['am_in'] == !NULL) {
    echo '<img src="../images/in.png">';
    }
    if ($row_io['am_out'] == !NULL) {
    echo '<img src="../images/out.png">';
    }
    if ($row_io['pm_in'] == !NULL)  {
    echo '<img src="../images/in.png">';
    }
    if ($row_io['pm_out'] == !NULL) {
    echo '<img src="../images/out.png">';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what value do you store in columns 'am_in','am_out' ,'pm_in','pm_out' (Datatype) ?

Comment: Did any of our answers provide what you need?  If not, we need feedback.

Answer (score 0):

For each one of your columns, I'd switch it to:

```
if ($row_io['column_name'] != NULL) {
```

I've never used `== !` before, so I'm not sure if it's valid, but I know `!=` is the preferred way of performing a "not equal to" check.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ((!empty($row_io['am_in'] && empty($row_io['am_out']) || (!empty($row_io['pm_in'] && empty($row_io['pm_out'])) {
    echo '<img src="../images/in.png">';
}else{
    echo '<img src="../images/out.png">';
}
?>
```

This will return true if they've checked in, but not out, for either AM or PM.  If they haven't checked in, or they've checked in and checked out, then it will return false.